# Devolver valor booleano sql y c#

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un pequeño problema. Capaz sea algo sonso, pero no lo puedo notar.
Estoy haciendo una consulta a la base de datos, que me tiene que decir si hay registros o no, mediante un count en la query.
Lo que hago es crear un método booleano, para que me retorne el true o el false. Pero cuando este vuelve a la capa de negocio, vuelve como falso. ¿Por qué es? ¿O simplemente estoy haciendo mal los métodos?

Consulta para sql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí, me arroja el valor true la variable.
Pero cuando entra a la capa de negocios ya se pone false:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay algo que no estoy haciendo bien y no lo noto? ¿O lo que hago no se puede realizar?

Comment: Le mandas `primerLogueo` y luego intentas cambiarlo dentro del método y luego lo devuelves. Si el metodo tira una excepcion, no hace nada y devuelve el mismo valor que `primerLogueo` tenía cuando entró al método... Y el método se llama `ConsultarRegistrosLogin`... Yo esperaría me trajera una lista de los registros de inicio de sesión... Pero devuelve un `bool`. Tienes que recordar que tu código probablemente sea mantenido y modificado por otra persona... Intenta sea lo más claro posible

Comment: La próxima vez, por favor el código como texto, no como imagen. Llevas dos años en el sitio.

Comment: Amigo el valor todavía no llego a actualizarse, porque no paso por el punto del breakpoint, si vas al método que recibe la variable, ya tiene el valor true.

Comment: Si, en eso tenés razón, lo mostré mal en el breakpoint, pero si me daba false, por la mal asignación que estaba haciendo. Gracias @ciberbull123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que te asegures que el método retorne lo que realmente estás buscando, dale una leve modificación:

```
public bool ConsultarRegistrosLogin(bool primerLogueo)
{
    var resultado = _dataEmpleados.ConsultarRegistrosLogin(primerLogeo);
    return resultado;
}
```

Es muy probable que lo resaltado sea el valor del input del método `ConsultarRegistrosLogin`.

Comment: Ahí va, ahora comprendí todo mejor. Muchas gracias broooo!!!!!!!

Comment: Para servirles :D Sigue desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 1):

Parece que no deberias agregar como para parametro el booleano. Cuando queres que algo te devuelva bool no se suele poner parametro un bool al llamarlo.

Entonces:

1. Saca como parametro el bool.
2. Crea una variable bool en la primer linea del cuerpo del metodo
3. Crea esa var con valor false.
4. Luego con un if si la query (mediante los parceos) devuelve true o mayor a 0.
5. Si te devuelve registro a esa var definida arriba le asignas true, y con el  else le asignas false

En conclusion, prueba basicamente de esa manera sacando el parametro y luego  define un var bool en la primer linea del metodo... luego seria la logica similar a como lo estas manejando.

No es tan especifico pero ojala al menos esta idea se acerque a la solucion o te dé alguna idea para mejorarlo.

Saludos

Comment: Ahora lo pruebo también! Gracias @jmr85